# Optimize random seeking of embedded video in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an `Embedded (synchronized with timeline)` clip in a flash movie.

I am controlling the `currentFrame` of the clip by dragging a slider left to right (to simulate rotating an object).

The problem is when I go forwards, motion is smooth, but if I drag to the left Flash cannot seem to efficiently play back in reverse and the motion is extremely jerky. Obviously I'm skipping frames depending upon the position of the mouse, but there is a very noticable lag when `currentFrame` is decreased vs. increased.

Is there a way to optimize an embedded timeline clip for reverse random seeking like this?

Possible solutions (untested) :

- Use video instead of embedded - I would expect this to make the situation worse though!
- Create a second reversed video for when scrolling to the left. This would probably double the file size.

Any other ideas?

Note: I am only changing the `currentFrame` of the clip on `onEnterFrame` to ensure I don't modify `currentFrame` too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer turned out to be relatively simple :-)

- Just add more keyframes when you encode the video to an FLV/F4V

When it's seeking backwards it's more likely to be able to find a keyframe to then calculate the frame you desire.

Found couple other people with the same problem - and some said it took some experimenting to find the right number of keyframes. Obviously adding keyframes increases the size of the document so you have to find a trade off between performance and filesize.

I tried 3 frames and it didn't increase the file size too much and works very well forward and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows you how to tween the timeline (frame by frame) using the Tweener tweening engine:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=67

http://code.google.com/p/tweener/